# How to format a varchar in a gridview in military time to standard time

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, formatting

There is a `varchar` column in the database table in this format of military time 1230 or 1750 or 1320 and that field get populated into a gridview in asp. I need to convert that string to standard time. I have tried the DateFormatString and nothing seems to work.

the asp is

```
<asp:BoundColumn DataField="ScanTime" SortExpression="ScanTime" ReadOnly="True" 
     HeaderText="Scan Time" DataFormatString="{0:hh}:{0:mm} {tt}">
<ItemStyle Width="80px"></ItemStyle>
</asp:BoundColumn>
```

that `DateFormatString` causes Input string was not in a correct format. error.

Please help I have tried combinations of `hh:mm` and things like that but since its a `varchar` I think its failing

Comment: The answer here is to fix the database: it's broken. It should be using a datetime data type instead.

Comment: I do not have control of the database, I can only query for the query but thanks for the comment

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
Dim myTime as String = "105"
Dim realTime As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(myTime.PadLeft(4, "0"))
```